# Why my function redirect without passing data in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to create flask app where my DNA will be converted to RNA.
But I can't pass the data using redirect. What could be wrong here?

**python code:**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    form = DNAForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # flash(f'Your dna is {form.dna.data.Upper()}', 'success')
        dna = form.dna.data.upper()
        rna = dna.maketrans('ACGT','UGCA')
        return redirect(url_for('home', rna=rna))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

**html code:**

```
{% if rna %}
   <h4>The RNA is: <span class="text-danger">{{ rna }}</span> </h4>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make redirect it will return this:

```
return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

So `rna` won't be passed to `index.html`

Here is how to fix it

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    form = DNAForm()
    rna = None
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        dna = form.dna.data.upper()
        rna = dna.maketrans('ACGT','UGCA')
        # if you don't want the form to be filled with previous data
        form.dna.data = ''

    return render_template('index.html', form=form, rna = rna)
```

Now when `form` gets submitted and validated it will give `rna` some value to display in `index.html`

Comment: Thank you. @Ine-io